# Latest Chrome on Android plays Baseline mp4 but not when delivered with HTTP Handler with Range Request headers

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, video

I have an mp4 file encoded with the Baseline and Constrained Baseline profiles.

When I place the mp4 file in a folder with an HTML file which uses a `<video>` tag to load the video it plays no problem.

However we have a HTTP Handler which adds Range-Request and ETag HTTP handlers to the deliver the file.  It works on Firefox running on Android, but not on Chrome.

The Range Request was added to allow users to jump to other sections of a long video.

Would the extra headers in the HTTP Response (which is the video file) stop Chrome on Android being able to show the video to the users?

extra:  I got remote debugging setup on Chrome/Android.  I can now step into my content http handler.  There is a 206 partial request that is used to stream mp4 videos to iOS clients.  In the 'Network' tab of Chrome developer tools there are usually a few entries for the chunked mp4, but on Chrome on Android the 206 only shows up once.  Something seems to blow up after that 1st 206 header is sent with the MP4 video (encoded with Constrained Baseline).  As mentioned when the file is just in a folder with the html file, Chrome 32 and 36 play the file as usual, but not when it coming from the handler.  Unfortunately the handler controls all the content, so all video files must come from there.

Comment: Your last sentence seems to be incomplete, but I've no idea what you meant to type. Can you edit it?

Comment: Is that ok.  I guess I got so frustrated I forgot how to write english.

Comment: @magister i have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975943/php-serve-mp4-chrome-provisional-headers-are-shown-request-is-not-finished-ye , did you solve it by any chance?

Comment: yes I did, I am not using PHP thou.  It appearred that on Chrome on Android that you have to serve the file with a 200 not a 206 partial.  I used a popular library, which at first was modified to act as a HTTP handler, but I changed it to use a ASP.NET MVC ActionResult.  If you can use C# its here:  https://github.com/tpeczek/Lib.Web.Mvc